# Matlab GUI, create two tabs

Tags: matlab, user-interface, tabs

I want to create two tabs within one GUI. One can show the plot of sine function, the other shows cone function. I can handle these two functions. but i do not know how to create two tabs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can look over here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by tabs you mean 'plotting area' then you likely need to create 2 axes objects and display each plot in its own axes. In GUIDE it's very easy...more info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/adding-components-to-the-gui.html).

Let's say you have axes1 and axes2, you can do this:

```
axes(axes1) % Make axes1 the current axes.
plot(sin(...))

axes(axes2) % Make axes2 the current axes
plot(...)
```

and that's it. Hope this is what you mean! If not sorry I misunderstood the question.

**EDIT**
I thought about it and I'm probably wrong about what I thought a tab is. Matlab does not allow to do it directly, although it might be possible with the GUI Layout Toolbox. Here is a submission from the FIle Exchange which could be interesting to you: [link here!](http://www.mathworks.ca/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11546-uitabpanel). Sorry abut the confusion.

Comment: I mean in this tab, GUI shows plot of sin, you cannot see cos: but in the other tab, GUI shows plot of cos, you cannot see sin. So i think you understand it at first .

Answer (score -2):

`uitab()` can be used for creating tabs. If you want to create tabs using guide it's currently not natively supported but possible with a work around I described [here](http://matlabtraining.com/blog/2016/03/creating-tabs-using-guide/).